# "AND" and "OR" statement in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

So I am trying to run a query that has multiples `AND`s and `OR`s. Here is the query:

```
SELECT
COUNT(DISTINCT t.id)
FROM tags t
WHERE t.description LIKE '%Name%'
AND t.description LIKE '%On-boarding%'
OR t.description LIKE '%Pending Approval Inventory%'
AND t.title = 'follow-up'
AND t.created_at >= now() ::date;
```

I only want records for today. The problem is that records from other dates that != today are included in the count, too. I can't quite figure out how to debug this query ... Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: Use parenthesis `()` to group (and control the order of evaluation of) your logical expressions. Also, today may be a good day to learn about [`EXPLAIN`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/using-explain.html).

Comment: [4.1.6. Operator Precedence](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-PRECEDENCE)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are wanting this:

```
SELECT
COUNT(DISTINCT t.id)
FROM tags t
WHERE ((t.description LIKE '%Name%'
AND t.description LIKE '%On-boarding%')
OR t.description LIKE '%Pending Approval Inventory%')
AND t.title = 'follow-up'
AND date_trunc('day', t.created_at) = date_trunc('day', now());
```

I also added parenthesis around your description filters.  I'm guess you want name and on-boarding together or it be pending approval inventory.

But the real trick here is to use the date_trunc function.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
COUNT(DISTINCT t.id)
FROM tags t
WHERE t.description LIKE '%Name%'
AND (t.description LIKE '%On-boarding%' OR t.description LIKE %Pending Approval Inventory%')
AND t.title = 'follow-up'
AND CONVERT(DATE,t.created_at) = CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE());
```

Here I have used T-SQL Build In Date function To cast, may be you need to use some build in functions in PostgreSQL.

Comment: date_trunc is a built in function in PostgreSQL that removes precision from timestamps/dates.  It is very similar to how Oracle handles dates.